# URL encoding issue in Phantom JS 2.1.1 while creating PDF

Tags: pdf, phantomjs, urlencode

URL is decoding by `Phantom JS 2.1.1` which causes the `signature` to be failed and getting `forbidden` `error`.

Am executing `command` as below:

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --debug=yes  rasterize.js http://example.com/?signature="%3CMSG%2B6%2BSigDat%23VER%2B5%2B3%2E0%2E1%23SYS%2B3%2BFAK%23CID%2B20%2B5f9f92bdd0633e59706b%23TIM%2B10%2B1915528386%23DAT%2B89%2Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fetest%2Ecom%2Eno%2Fbill%2Fbill%2F456254475%2F6476882648%2test%2Ehtml%3FbillType%3Dcom%23P7S%2B352%2B"
```

But in apache Server log URL comes as shown below: That is all `%2E`  decoded with `DOT` (`.`).

```
http://example.com/?signature="%3CMSG%2B6%2BSigDat%23VER%2B5%2B3.0.1%23SYS%2B3%2BFAK%23CID%2B20%2B5f9f92bdd0633e59706b%23TIM%2B10%2B1915528386%23DAT%2B89%2Bhttps%3A%2F%2Fetest.com.no%2Fbill%2Fbill%2F456254475%2F6476882648%2test.html%3FbillType%3Dcom%23P7S%2B352%2B
```

I tried with `Phanotm JS 1.8.1` from a different machine , But there `URL` is not changing and everything works as expected. But I have to migrate from `1.8.1` to `2.1.1` and so that am no longer be able to use `1.8.1 Phantom JS`. Any help will really be appreciated!